# Buying contracts/agreements from another company

Tags: contract-law

**Company A** creates agreements/contracts with instructors who have created courses to sell online.  The agreement/contract is signed by the instructors and owned by **Company A**.

**Company A** wants to sell the company to **Company B**.  However, **Company B** would rather buy the courses and the agreements/contracts and allow **Company A** to dissolve.  Is this possible without having the instructors sign another agreement/contract with **Company B**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible without having the instructors sign another agreement/contract with Company B?

Generally speaking, yes. In fact, this is what usually happens in company acquisitions. The buyer usually does not need to enter new contracts with seller's providers, employees, and customers.

Company B needs to ensure that (1) the contracts to which company A is a party do not contain language that render those contracts exceptions to the aformentioned general case; and (2) its contract with company A clearly establishes the transfer of company A's rights/entitlements to company B. Similarly, company A will want to ensure that also the transfer of its obligations is reflected in its contract with company B.